# Python function: if link in one dataset is a part of a link in another dataset, assign 1, else 0

Tags: python, pandas, function

Sample datasets i have:

df1:

| ID | Page Link |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | http://example1/path1/ru/path2/path3 |
| 2 | https://example2.com/path1 |
| 3 | https://example3.subdomain |

df2:

| ID | Link |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | http://example1/path1/ru |
| 2 | https://example2.com/path1 |
| 3 | https://example3.subdomain/path2 |

in df1 I need to create a column ['Contains'], which has values 1 or 0. If df1 links are a part of links in df2, then ['Contains']=1, else 0

so that end result looks like this:

df1

| ID | Page Link | Contains |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | http://example1/path1/ru/path2/path3 | 1 |
| 2 | https://example2.com/path1 | 1 |
| 3 | https://example3.subdomain | 0 |

I tried this:

```
def assign(column):
    for link in df2['Link']:
        if re.search(link, column):
            contains=1
        else
            contains=0
    return contains

df1['Contains']=df1['Page Link'].apply(assign)
```

This didn't return the result I expected

```
leads['Marketing Team']=leads['Page Link'].apply(assign_marketing)
```

Comment: Do you need a match per ID or a simple match with any link?

Comment: match with link

Comment: but all links? or only the link with same ID?

Comment: @mozway no, not the same id, ignore id

Comment: @mozway if there is a match between any links, return 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function that you use does not stop when it finds a match, and may later "change its mind." Here is a fixed version:

```
def assign(column):
    for link in df2['Link']:
        if re.search(link, column):
            return 1 # Return at once!
    return 0
```

If the match is always at the beginning, you can replace the expensive `re.search()` with a much faster `startswith()`:

```
def assign(column):
    for link in df2['Link']:
        if link.startswith(column):
            return 1 # Return at once!
    return 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with regex - join values by `|` of `df2.Link` with escape:

```
import re

regex = '|'.join(re.escape(x) for x in df2.Link)
df1['Contains'] = df1['Page Link'].str.contains(regex).astype(int)

print (df1)
   ID                             Page Link  Contains
0   1  http://example1/path1/ru/path2/path3         1
1   2            https://example2.com/path1         1
2   3            https://example3.subdomain         0
```

If need test all links use nested list comprehension - it should be slow if large both DataFrames:

```
df1['Contains'] = [int(any(x in link for x in df2['Link'])) for link in df1['Page Link']]
print (df1)
   ID                             Page Link  Contains
0   1  http://example1/path1/ru/path2/path3         1
1   2            https://example2.com/path1         1
2   3            https://example3.subdomain         0
```

Comment: It returned only 0 value for all

Comment: @DilraboKodirova - Added another answer.

Answer (score 1):

The question is not highly explicit, so in case you want to check the link match **per ID**, you can use:

```
s = df1['ID'].map(df2.set_index('ID')['Link'])

df1['Contains'] = [int(b in a) if b else 0 for a,b in zip(df1['Page Link'], s)]
```

output:

```
   ID                             Page Link  Contains
0   1  http://example1/path1/ru/path2/path3         1
1   2            https://example2.com/path1         1
2   3            https://example3.subdomain         0
```